# Showing a link with Javascript based on log-in status

Tags: menus, javascript

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '';
} else {
echo '<a onclick="ppOpen('#login_panel', '800',1)" href=\"javascript:\">Entrar</a>';
}
?>
```

Hello, I'm trying to make this work but i'm not sure how to do the syntax.... any help would be great! thanks!

Comment: `<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {echo '';
 } else {
echo "<a onclick=\"ppOpen('#login_panel', '800',1)\" href=\"javascript:\">Entrar</a>";
}
?>` I've done this and it works, do you think is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is string escape problem with PHP Syntax

Correct Code:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '';
} else {
echo '<a onclick="ppOpen(\'#login_panel\', \'800\',1)" href="javascript:void(0)">Entrar</a>';
}
?>
```